# How to force a binary application to use a SOCKS Proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, socks, tunnel

I want to tunnel the tcp traffic from several Windows 10 applications which does not offer proxy settings, through s SOCKS proxy.

I tried FreeCap and WideCap but the are not supported by Windows 10.
Then I found the tool injectSOCKS ( https://sourceforge.net/projects/injectsocks/ ) - it can socksify any binary but it is not very stable and works not with any binary.

Are there some other tools (maybe for console without GUI) which can socksify a binary?

Comment: You can set a system wide proxy in windows: Setting - > Network and Internet -> proxy -> Manual Proxy Setup.

Comment: but not for example for Outlook 2016. The system wide proxy only supports http/https/ftp connections. It does not work for applications which does not offer any proxy support. I want to tunnel TCP 993 or TCP 22 connections.

Comment: Proxifier (https://www.proxifier.com) works fine